# How do you return mocha's test results from puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, frontend, puppeteer

I want to run my [mochajs](https://mochajs.org) front-end unit tests in a headless browser, specifically using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). So, following the very simple example on the `mochajs` page [here](https://mochajs.org/#browser-specific-methods), I am running a basic unit test and am seeing `mocha`'s results and they are rendered in the *page* as they should be. I see that they would also be rendered to chromium's `console` when I load the simple example in a real browser. All great. However, I want to return these results from the call to this script.  How do I *return* these test results from running `mochajs` in `puppeteer`?  In other words:

```
$ node my-script-running-mocha-in-puppeteer.js

  Array
    #indexOf()
      ✓ should return -1 when the value is not present


  1 passing (9ms)
```

My code basically looks like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

 puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`
     /* 
        HTML page with mocha, unit tests and source.
     */
  `);  

  // Get page content
  const content = await page.content();

  // I see the mocha test result in the page but now I 
  // want to return them from this script.
  console.log(content);
  await browser.close();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are saying, that mocha is also printing the data into the console, this is likely the easiest way to get the test results.

#### Simple approach

To simply mirror the IO of the browser including any data logged to console, you can enable the option `dumpio` when launching the browser:

```js
puppeteer.launch({ dumpio: true })
```

Quote from the docs for [`puppeteer.launch`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions):

> `dumpio` <`boolean`> Whether to pipe the browser process stdout and stderr into `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`. Defaults to `false`.

Be aware, that this will also print other information from the browser into the console. If you are looking only for the console data, you can use the second option.

#### Only logging calls to `console.log`, etc.

To only get the data which is logged to `console.log` or `console.info`, etc. you can listen to the [`console`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#event-console) event.

```js
page.on('console', consoleMessage => {
    console.log(consoleMessage.text());
    if (consoleMessage.type() === 'error') {
        // handle error output
    }
});
```

This way, you can grab all output going into the console. You can even use [`consoleMessage.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#consolemessagetype) to differentiate between error, warnings and normal output.

Comment: Nice, thank you, @thomas!  The `console` event handler did the trick.

Comment: Specific to the `mochajs` setup, be sure to set your reporter to `spec` to get the results into the console.